# Install logstash using the Deb file

Tags: ubuntu, java, logstash

I have installed Java 7 and Java 8 on my machine and java -version returns the correct version when I change the environment variables. When I go to install Logstash using the deb I receive the follow message:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of logstash:
 logstash depends on java7-runtime-headless | java6-runtime-headless | j2re1.7; however:
  Package java7-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package java6-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package j2re1.7 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package logstash (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Errors were encountered while processing:
 logstash
```

I've tried to install these java versions but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you install Java?

Comment: Hi, here is how I did it:                                      1) tar -xzvf server-jre-7u71-linux-x64.gz
2) mv jre1.7.0_71/ /usr/local/java/                              3) update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_71/bin/java" 1                       then I added this to the /etc/profiles nano /etc/profile
4) JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_7
PATH=$PATH:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JRE_HOME
export PATH